# I have been trying to link my node to Mongo Db to local host but it keep throwing me error

Tags: node.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
main().catch(err => console.log(err));
async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');
}
```

eroor

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:807:32)    at E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:340:10
at E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at promiseOrCallback (E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)    
at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1140:10)
at Mongoose.connect (E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:339:20)
at main (E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\index.js:5:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\index.js:3:1)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14) {
```

reason: TopologyDescription {
type: 'Unknown',
servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
stale: false,
compatible: true,
heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
localThresholdMS: 15,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
}
}

Comment: Can you please provide the piece of code that used to connect mongoDB

Comment: const mongoose = require('mongoose');
main().catch(err => console.log(err));
async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');
}

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the IPV6 that MongoDB has disabled by default, by using the given command also I'm adding a reference for your understanding. `mongod --ipv6`

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-mongodb-configuration/

I tried with the given piece of code and its working now,

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/db_name',
{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  }
);
```

https://www.section.io/engineering-education/nodejs-mongoosejs-mongodb/

Comment: Now it throwing me some new errors

Comment: please provide the trace details.

Comment: MongoParseError: option usefindandmodify is not supported

Comment: Oh ok, that is a version dependency error, can you please remove  `useFindAndModify: false` and try again.

Comment: hey,it agains give me an error

Comment: same? please post errors as well. Also which version of node and mongoose your using?

Comment: i am editing the errors please see to it

Comment: i have uploaded it as a new question...can u please see to it.

Comment: here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71285249/how-to-fix-the-error-of-connecting-mongoose-to-node-js