# How to fix the error of connecting mongoose to node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I made sure that my `mongod` is running.

I have checked from services that my Mongo Db is running and also restarted it so many times.

I have tried using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`

I have also enable the `mongod --ipv6`.But it still giving me these errors.

I have reinstalled mongoose and Mongo Db.But it still throwing me error.

Here is my index.js code

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/db_name',
    {
    
      useUnifiedTopology: true
     }
    );
```

here is my json file.

```json
    {
     "name": "new-folder",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "description": "",
     "main": "index.js",
     "scripts": {
     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
     "author": "",
     "license": "ISC",
     "dependencies": {
     "express": "^4.17.3",
     "mongodb": "^4.4.0",
     "mongoose": "^6.2.3",
     "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
     }
    }
```

Here is the error Im getting.

```
    E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:807
    const serverSelectionError = new ServerSelectionError();
                               ^

     MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:807:32)    at E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:340:10
    at E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)    
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1140:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:339:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\index.js:31:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10) {
    reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        _hostAddress: HostAddress { isIPv6: false, host: 'localhost', port: 27017 },
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 292201728,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:381:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:301:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:640:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:520:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
            at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
     }
    }

    Node.js v17.4.0
```

Comment: how did you make sure that the mongo running on localhost port 27017?

Comment: i have noted down that from mongoose documentation which is present online

Comment: are you running the mongodb from docker or or as service? if it's a docker container, make sure that it's running and port forwarded correctly by running `docker ps` and if it's as system service, check with: `sudo systemctl status mongod`
also please use some client like robomongo and connect to the DB yourself

Comment: Actually I started new, and its a system service, I guess.

Comment: ok then please run `sudo systemctl status mongod` and make sure that it says `active (running)`

Comment: I have to run this command in my command prompt?

Comment: yes, make sure that it's running

Comment: I typed mongo sudo systemctl status mongod in my command prompt then it gives failed to load: systemctl
exiting with code -3

Comment: I dont' know wich OS you are using but check the `mongod` service status

Comment: I am on windows

Comment: run this command on cmd: 
`mongod --port 27017 --dbpath C:\MongoDB\data\db` and then rerun your app

Comment: it gives the same error as mentioned above

Comment: have you tried to connect mongodb with mongodb-compass ???

Answer (score 0):

bro don't use { useUnifiedTopology: true } this command. instead try it without this code and add a function to it like this

```
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Database created!");
    db.close();
  }
```